# Why can't my User login to the azure portal?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

**Background**: I am trying to setup my azure infrastructure to deploy my new web app. I am working with an external contractor cloud engineer and I only want her to be able to setup my cloud infrastructure.

**Steps**: I have 1 Subscription and 1 Resource Group. I have created a User in my organisation (so not a guest) in Azure AD - I will share these details with her.

I have put this new User inside a User Group and I have permissioned the User Group (as a Contributor) against my Resource Group. I have shared the username and password with her.

**Problem**: When she logs on to portal.azure.com she gets the message *"Your sign-in was successful, but you don't have permission to access this resource."*

Clearly I am missing something? I thought this was straightforward... alas

TIA.

Comment: For that AD user, what "Role assignement" have you done? Refer to this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal?tabs=current)

Comment: The User is in my custom User Group and the User Group has a Role Assignment of Contributor against the Subscription - ideally I want to permission at the Resource Group only

Comment: I think you need to add as "Co-Administrator" , see this Azure [Roles documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/rbac-and-directory-admin-roles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VPN....

I switched off my VPN and it then worked just fine. No idea why but it works and I can now log straight in to the portal

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this may happen due to the `internal policy`, make sure to recheck them once again.

After this if you create a personal login detail separately then it will work out.

Here is the reference of [Your sign-in was successful but you don't have permission to access this resource](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/msonline/en-US/4e957536-3c4f-4bd4-b0fb-96563557ba09/your-signin-was-successful-but-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-this-resource) for the same above.

If the user is a guest user incase, then administrator of guest tenant will delete your account from their tenant.
Here is the [Reference](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/66498#issuecomment-732781831) given by @Amanpreet Singh.

*Common steps to be followed as below,*

- After login to the Azure portal as a Admin.
- Go to `Azure Active Directory`
- Select the `All services`, then Azure AD `Conditional Access`.

Here you can select the restriction policy and / or make sure to recheck the Assignments from the `Users & Groups` of various permissions for your given user.